# Collection of real valued functions on a set X. Sigma Algebras.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of real-valued functions on $X$ such that the constant functions are in $\mathcal{F}$ and $f+g, fg$, and $cf$ are in $\mathcal{F}$ whenever $f, g \in \mathcal{F}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f \in \mathcal{F}$ whenever $f_n \rightarrow f$ and each $f_n \in \mathcal{F}$. Define the function 
$$ \chi_A(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & x \in A \\
0, & x \notin A
\end{cases}$$ Prove that $\mathcal{A} = \{A \subset X : \chi_A \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

This is a problem from Richard Bass' Real Analysis book. I don't want answers to the question, but I would like some hints on understanding what the question is asking.

- What do the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ look like?
- What does it mean $\chi_A \in \mathcal{F}$
- Is $\chi_A(x)$ not just $0$s and $1$s

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit I reread the question and I had a minor typo in the $\mathcal{A}$ set. Not sure if that changes a lot in reading the problem.

Comment: Yes, now the definiton of the set $\mathcal A$ is okay. $\mathcal A$ is a set of sets $A$ such that $\chi_A$ is either constant or can be written as a limit of functions of $\mathcal F$. Where comes your second question from? This does not make sense. Can you check if $\emptyset, X\in \mathcal F$?

Comment: My second question is with respect to the $\mathcal{A}$ set. What does $\chi_A$ look like?

Comment: Okay, for example take $X=[0,1]$ and $A=[1,2]$. Then we have $A\subset X$ and $\chi_A$ is constant $1$ on $A$ and else $0$. I hope that helps.

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit $[1,2] \subset [0,1]$?

Comment: I ment $[0,1/2]$, sorry.